# Is there a certain benefit in declaring an object using a class and assign it to another class?

Tags: java, class, object

During a Java course in my University we teach this example. While I certainly understand how this works, I fail to imagine a real life example where this practice might be useful. In my eyes it makes the code harder to understand. More specifically, is there a certain benefit in declaring an object using a class and assign it to another class (`Small smallBig  =  new Big();`) and can you give me a simple scenario where this practice might be useful?

The code:

```
public class Small { 
  public int value; 
  public Small() {value = 10;} 
  public int getValue() {return value;} 
}

public class Big extends Small { 
  public int value; 
  public Big() {value = 40;} 
  public int getValue() {return value-10;} 
} 


public class Main { 

    public static void main (String args[]) { 
        Small small  =  new Small(); 
        Small smallBig  =  new Big(); 
        Big   big  =  new Big(); 

        System.out.println(small.getValue()); 
        System.out.println(smallBig.getValue()); 
        System.out.println(big.getValue()); 
        System.out.println(small.value); 
        System.out.println(smallBig.value); 
        System.out.println(big.value); 
        small = (Small) big; 
        System.out.println(small.getValue()); 
        System.out.println(small.value); 
        big = (Big) small; 

        System.out.println(big.getValue()); 
        System.out.println(big.value); 
    } 
}
```

The output:

```
10
30 
30
10
10 
40
30 
10
30 
40
```

Comment: Google "Polymorphism". Long story short: You define an interface everyone can rely upon and hide the implementation detail. Basic example: Java collection API where `List` is an interface which defines how every list should behave and `ArrayList` is an implementation of lists using an array as a backing concept.

Comment: Careful with your terminology.  You're not "declaring an object and assigning it to another class," you're declaring a variable of a type, and assigning it a newly instantiated object of a subtype.  You declare variables; you instantiate objects.

Comment: @IanMcLaird I'll remember that, maybe you could alter the title so it fits the subject better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a method that operates on both `Big`s and `Small`s will help to illustrate the point better.

Assuming the same class definitions you already used in the question, you can create a method that prints both `getValue()` and `value`.  Because `Big extends Small`, you need only one method.

```
public void printValues(Small val) {
    System.out.println("getValue() == " + val.getValue());
    System.out.println("value == " + val.value);
}
```

If you *didn't* have that relationship, and ability to assign `Big` objects to `Small` variables (remember: passing a value to a method is the same as assigning a variable), you'd need to have two different methods to handle this situation.

It helps to think of the `extends` keyword as meaning `A Big is a more specific type of Small`.  In general, it's best to write methods that handle things using the *least* specific type that you can, because it will allow that method to handle situations you haven't even imagined yet.

For example, suppose that somewhere down the line, somebody decided to write

```
class Medium extends Small {
    public Medium() {value = 20;} 
    public int getValue() {return value-5;} 
}
```

The `printValues()` method can already handle this class, even though we didn't know about `Medium`s when we wrote it.

Comment: So basically it's a smarter use of the code. I still don't feel very comfortable on using it in my own projects though, feels like it reduces the readability but I guess it'll have to grow on me.

Comment: It will grow on you.  In the long run, you'll actually find that sort of thing very natural and readable.  The comment above on "coding to an interface" is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this senario it'd be useful:

```
public class Person{
  Mobility mobility;
  Person(Mobility mobility){this.mobility = mobility;}
}
public class Mobility{
  int speed;
  public Mobility(int speed){this.speed = speed;}
}
public class Car extends Mobility{
  public Car(int speed){super(speed);}
}


public class Main { 

public static void main (String args[]) { 
    Car ferrari = new Car(1000);
    Person john = new Person(ferrari);
}
```

}

Hope i could help you.

Comment: You should explain _how_ it would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case you are using getValue as Template method "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern"

Let take you example with little twist

```
public class Small { 
public int value; 
public Small() {value = 10;} 
public int getValue() {// this method fetches data from database}
```

}

```
public class Big extends Small { 
public int value; 
public Big() {value = 40;} 
public int getValue() {//this method fetches data from xml} 


public class Big2 extends Small { 
 public int value; 
 public Big() {value = 40;} 
 public int getValue() {//this method fetched data from some server}
```

}

As u can see the implementation of getValue is changing. Each sub class provides its own implementation of getValue.
Thus it gives my super class an opportunity to use different implementation of this method at run time (in you case). I Hope it makes it clear. Have a look at Template method pattern , you will get a better idea.

Comment: Yes, the example is clear. Although, in a large project won't this practice reduce the readability of the code or do I get this feeling because I'm not comfortable with it yet?

Comment: Well no . As you know we program to interfaces , now it does not mean that we have to make a separate interface and have all the class implement it (We would end up with  load's of interfaces). Interfaces are promarly used to connect two components or modules . A class public methods are its interface. if a module say X contains say 4 objects , these 4 objects will use each others public method (public interace) to get the work done , but if i might have a seperate interface for the module so that i can procide a seperate implementation for it.
Hopes it make it much clear.